# Difficult tainted kernel message - anyone know the source?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, dmesg

It lists so many things that I can not tell the source. I see iee80211 so I thought it might be a network packet, but than I see IRQ and also modules being listed so it is really convulated.

Ubuntu xenial with 4.15.0-43-generic kernel.

Note: I ran mem test for like 24 hours and had no memory errors

```
 [16543.995570] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 0 at /build/linux-hwe-O570pP/linux-hwe-4.15.0/net/mac80211/rx.c:629 ieee80211_rx_napi+0x867/0xa40 [mac80211]
[16543.995572] Modules linked in: ccm xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp bridge stp ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables appletalk ipx p8023 psnap p8022 llc snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(POE) arc4 wmi_bmof snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic rtl8192ee btcoexist rtl_pci rtlwifi amd64_edac_mod edac_mce_amd snd_hda_intel kvm_amd snd_hda_codec mac80211 snd_hda_core kvm snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_timer irqbypass input_leds snd ccp soundcore cfg80211 shpchp wmi mac_hid i2c_piix4 k10temp ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi nct6775 hwmon_vid autofs4 btrfs
[16543.995623]  zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt hid_generic fb_sys_fops crct10dif_pclmul drm crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc ipmi_devintf usbhid aesni_intel hid aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd ipmi_msghandler r8169 ahci mii libahci gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
[16543.995659] CPU: 7 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/7 Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[16543.995660] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./AB350 Pro4, BIOS P4.60 01/15/2018
[16543.995686] RIP: 0010:ieee80211_rx_napi+0x867/0xa40 [mac80211]
[16543.995688] RSP: 0018:ffff952d9edc3e20 EFLAGS: 00010297
[16543.995690] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff952d739f5a00 RCX: 000000000000001b
[16543.995692] RDX: 0000000000000080 RSI: 0000000000000009 RDI: ffff952d88bb0760
[16543.995693] RBP: ffff952d9edc3ef0 R08: 0000000000027120 R09: 0000000000000100
[16543.995694] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000000
[16543.995696] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000006 R15: ffff952d88bb0760
[16543.995698] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff952d9edc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[16543.995700] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[16543.995701] CR2: 00007f196f00a000 CR3: 0000000407a2c000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
[16543.995702] Call Trace:
[16543.995705]  <IRQ>
[16543.995713]  ? __free_pages+0x19/0x30
[16543.995717]  ? kfree+0x161/0x190
[16543.995721]  ? skb_free_head+0x21/0x30
[16543.995742]  ieee80211_tasklet_handler+0xc0/0xd0 [mac80211]
[16543.995746]  ? __kfree_skb_flush+0x30/0x40
[16543.995750]  tasklet_action+0x100/0x120
[16543.995753]  __do_softirq+0xf5/0x28f
[16543.995756]  irq_exit+0xb8/0xc0
[16543.995759]  do_IRQ+0x57/0xd0
[16543.995762]  common_interrupt+0x84/0x84
[16543.995763]  </IRQ>
[16543.995768] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xa7/0x300
[16543.995769] RSP: 0018:ffffbd92819cfe60 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffdd
[16543.995772] RAX: ffff952d9ede2880 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 000000000000001f
[16543.995773] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000025b7c40c RDI: 0000000000000000
[16543.995774] RBP: ffffbd92819cfe98 R08: ffff952d9ede16a4 R09: 0000000000000018
[16543.995775] R10: ffffbd92819cfe30 R11: 00000000000010dd R12: 0000000000000002
[16543.995777] R13: ffff952d80375e00 R14: ffffffff90d806f8 R15: 00000f0bf0a7aa24
[16543.995782]  cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[16543.995786]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
[16543.995788]  do_idle+0x197/0x200
[16543.995792]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[16543.995795]  start_secondary+0x1ab/0x200
[16543.995799]  secondary_startup_64+0xa5/0xb0
[16543.995801] Code: ff 48 8b 95 70 ff ff ff 4c 8b ab d8 00 00 00 4c 8b b2 d8 00 00 00 e9 35 fa ff ff 48 89 de 4c 89 ff e8 ee 29 fe ff e9 76 fa ff ff <0f> 0b 48 89 df e8 ef 2a 30 ce e9 7d f8 ff ff 4c 89 ff 44 8b a5 
[16543.995846] ---[ end trace 666a1d8f8ce5630a ]---
```

Comment: My guess would be one or more of the nvidia modules. "Tainted P OE" means that there are proprietary module(s), Out of tree module(s) and Unsigned module(s) loaded into the kernel. This may or may not have anything to do with the issue you are having.

Comment: @icarus exactly, the taint matches the NVIDIA modules listed as “(POE)”.